# How to definition sum Abelian category?

Tags: category-theory

Sorry for my bad English.

Let $\cal A$ be Abelian category, and $A$ be object of $\cal A$.
$\{B_i\}_{I\in I}$ are family of subobject of $A$.

Then, how we define sum $\Sigma_{I\in I}B_i$ which is subobject of A?

(In this case, I don' t mean $\Sigma_{I\in I}B_i$ as coproduct. )

Comment: Take the image in $A$ of the coproduct.